# Как организовать работу с Docker и Git

Tags: node.js, git, docker

Друзья, объясните пожалуйста вкратце, как обычно в компаниях организовывают воркфлоу с git и docker? Приложение - graphql сервер на node.js.

С git понял всё, кроме разницы между ветками release и master, а так же работы с тегами. А вот сам процесс деплоя, сервер непрерывной интеграции (или как оно там называется), тесты и всё такое - это вообще тёмный лес. Уже все туториалы с рутреккера перекачал, ничего найти не могу. Расскажите пожалуйста, что происходит с кодом дальше после ветки develop и заканчивая продакшном? Как автоматизировать процесс деплоя?

У меня сейчас всё по-колхозному - клонирую репозиторий на сервер, собираю контейнер и запускаю. Но знаю, что есть правильный путь :) Заранее спасибо!

Comment: На тему ci\cd есть довольно подробная книжка Jez Humble, David Farley Continuous Delivery Reliable Software Releases through Build, Test, and Deployment Automation 2010, правда на английском.

Comment: Правильных путей нет, каждый сам выбирает себе методологию. У нас в компании например (500+ программистов) в разных командах по-разному устроено. И даже наш один отдел с разными подрядчиками использовал разные методы. Этот ваш вопрос увы, слишком общий, чтобы на него можно было ответить однозначно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> С git понял всё, кроме разницы между ветками release и master, а так же работы с тегами

Почитать про [gitflow](https://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/).

В ветку `master` попадают `hotfix` или `release`. `release` из `develop`, когда сделаны будут все features. Все `feature/*` начинаются от develop и в него же попадают после завершения. `hotfix` вливаются в `master`. `develop` синхронизируется с master. Теги показывают версию приложения.

Это оригинальный `gitflow`.

Советую использовать упрощенную версию. Ветки `release` не создавать. `master` - всегда рабочая версия приложения. Выключаем `push` в `master`. Только `pull requests`. `develop` синхронизируется с `master`. `feature/*` и `fix/*` начинаются из `develop` и после проверки `pull request` вливаются в `master`. Теги везде.

> CI and CD

Тема обширная. Читаем про `DevOps`.

> CI

На примере `github` и `Travis CI`. Когда делается `push` в `master`, срабатывает `hook` из Travis запускает написанный скрипт в `.travis.yml`. Прогоняет тесты. После успешного завершения собирает `image` и заливает в `registry` (или dockerhub). Пример [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/dockemacs/blob/master/.travis.yml).

> CD

`image` залит в `registy`. Запускаем `deploy` c новыми версиями, если что-то не запускается - делаем `rollback`.

> git push -> test -> build image -> push image -> deploy

Все эти шаги автоматизированы.

> клонирую репозиторий на сервер, собираю контейнер

Эти шаги делаются либо `CI` или на машине разработчика. Контейнер всегда попадает на `production` из `registry`.